# extract specific portions of a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file as follows:

```
A    B  C  D  E
1    1  2  1  1e8
2    1  2  3  1e5
3    2  3  2  2000
50   2  3  2  2000
80   2  3  2  2000
...
1    2  5  6  1000
4    2  4  3  1e4
50   3  6  4  5000
120  3  5  2  2000
...
2  3  2  3  5000
3  3  4  5  1e9
4  3  2  3  1e6
7  3  2  3  43
...
```

I need a code to go through this text file and extract lines with the same number in first columns[A] and save in different files,

for example for the first column = 1 and ...

```
1  1  2  1  1e8
1  2  5  6  1000
```

I wrote code with while loop, but the problem is that this file is very big and with while loop it does this work for the numbers which does not exist in text and it takes very very long to finish,

Thanks for your help

Comment: didn't get you? can you be more specific?

Comment: A `for` loop, building a `dict` where each element of the first column is a `key` and the `value` is a `list` of all the related elements should be enough. If your problem is instead the time it takes to go through the file, you need to quantify a 'very big' file and show your code

Comment: I need to extract the lines which first column [A] has same number in them for example for [A]= 1 save data in a text, or for [A]=2  save the data in another text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Warning

Both of the examples below will overwrite files called `input_<number>.txt` in the path they are run in.

### Using `awk`

```
rm input_[0-9]*.txt; awk '/^[0-9]+[ \t]+/{ print >> "input_"$1".txt" }' input.txt
```

The front part `/^[0-9]+[ \t]+/` does a regex match to select only lines which start with an integer number, the second part `{ print >> "input_"$1".txt" }` prints those lines into a file named `input_<number>.txt`, with the corresponding lines for every number found in the first column of the file.

### Using Python

```
import sys
import os

fn = sys.argv[1]
name, ext = os.path.splitext(fn)

with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        ind = line.split()[0]
        try:
            ind = int(int)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        try:
            d[ind].write(line)
        except KeyError:
            d[ind] = open(name + "_{}".format(ind) + ext, "w")
            d[ind].write(line)

    for dd in d.values():
        dd.close()
```

### Using Python (avoiding too many open file handles)

In this case you have to remove any old output files before you run the code manually, using `rm input_[0-9]*.txt`

```
import sys
import os

fn = sys.argv[1]
name, ext = os.path.splitext(fn)

with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        ind = line.split()[0]
        try:
            ind = int(int)
        except ValueError:
            continue

        with open(name + "_{}".format(ind) + ext, "a") as d:
            d.write(line)
```

### Raising the limit of the number of open file handles

If you are sudoer on your machine, you can increase the limit of open file handles for a process by using `ulimit -n <number>`, as per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux).

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot, but for some files which are very big, it gives me the "awk: cannot open "input_1645477.txt" for output (Too many open files)" error, and it just save the first three lines in the new file, not more, and I have the same error in python,

Comment: Oh, well, you could close and reopen the file handle (at least in Python) dafter each iteration, but that will probably be much slower. I can edit the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: @poria My pleasure.